# Multi-dimensional Array Accordion in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, accordion

http://plnkr.co/edit/v11KtXMsABkJa2dS

When we have an array as below:

```
 $scope.groups = [
  "abc": [
    {
      title: "Title - 1",
      content: "Content - 1"
    },
    {
      title: "Title - 2",
      content: "Content - 2"
    }
  ],
  "def": [
    {
      title: "Title - 3",
      content: "Content - 3"
    },
    {
      title: "Title - 4",
      content: "Content - 4"
    }
  ] 
];
```

Want to display the keys as Accordion headings and on-click show the list of title and content pairs.

```
<uib-accordion close-others="oneAtATime">
    <uib-accordion-group ng-repeat="(group, grlist) in groups" ng-scroll="(group, grlist) in groups" is-open="group.isOpen" ng-click="updateOpenStatus()">
        <uib-accordion-heading>
            {{group}}
        </uib-accordion-heading>
        <div ng-repeat="val in grlist" class="list-group-item">
                <span>{{val.title}}</span>
                <span>{{val.content}}</span>
          </div>

    </uib-accordion-group>
</uib-accordion>
```

Also, would it be possible to show in batches of 10 with refresh button when if number of (title, content) pairs per group is very large ?

Answer (score 0):

Show first 10 items and 'show more' button. If user click on 'show more' button next 10 will be loaded.

```
<div ng-init="page=0">
  <div ng-repeat="val in grlist.slice(page, page+10)" class="list-group-item">
     <span>{{val.title}}</span>
     <span>{{val.content}}</span>
  </div>
  <span>Page: {{page + 1}}</span>
  <button ng-click="page = page + 1">Show more</button>
</div>
```